# WMI - Read PCI Configuration space

Tags: c#, c++, windows, assembly, wmi

I need some help with accessing PCI configuration space for educational purposes.

I need to read some registers:

- Header Type (Check is device is BUS)
- Base registers INPUT/OUTPUT
- Base registers ROM memory.
- Class code register.

So, I can easily get PCI list through WMI(c#) -

```
new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID LIKE 'PCI%'");
```

But, I can't find where I can find register which I seek above(Header Type,IO,ROM MEM,Class Code).
So I need help.

Or how can I get conf. adress space without WMI? I know some software which can output that information in bit form - Everest [[Screen]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJPqH.png) and RWEverything [[Screen]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/somsb.png). How can I read it by c# code in .txt for example [[example]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeoCO.png)?